# how to sort array inside collection in mongoDB using node js

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a collection of queries,data stored on the records look like the following.i want to sort according to the  id or the date inside the array in descending orders

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e71fa3ab004192b349e4a06",
        "QUERIES": [
            {
                "_id": "5e71fa3ab004192b349e4a07",
                "QUERY": "1",
                "USER_ID": "5e6f1c5b8451307f782d0994",
                "USER_NAME": "a2",
                "createdAt": "2020-03-18T10:38:50.247Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e71fa46b004192b349e4a08",
                "QUERY": "2",
                "USER_ID": "5e6f1c5b8451307f782d0994",
                "USER_NAME": "a1",
                "createdAt": "2020-03-18T10:39:02.451Z"
            }
        ],
        "TICKET_ID": "5e70f4fa47df9479502f7937"
]
```

Expected output

```
[
        {
            "_id": "5e71fa3ab004192b349e4a06",
            "QUERIES": [

                {
                    "_id": "5e71fa46b004192b349e4a08",
                    "QUERY": "2",
                    "USER_ID": "5e6f1c5b8451307f782d0994",
                    "USER_NAME": "a1",
                    "createdAt": "2020-03-18T10:39:02.451Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5e71fa3ab004192b349e4a07",
                    "QUERY": "1",
                    "USER_ID": "5e6f1c5b8451307f782d0994",
                    "USER_NAME": "a2",
                    "createdAt": "2020-03-18T10:38:50.247Z"
                }
            ],
            "TICKET_ID": "5e70f4fa47df9479502f7937"
    ]
```

Comment: Are you using MongoDB directly or something like Mongoose?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54366459/how-to-sort-array-of-objects-node-js-and-mongoose?rq=1. is that what you want?

Comment: using `mongoose`  for handling MongoDB Operations

Comment: the question I have pointed you out to is what you want?

Comment: I want mongoDB query code for getting the expected output,which is already mentioned on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $unwind: "$QUERIES" },
   { $sort: { "QUERIES.createdAt": -1 } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { _id: "$_id", TICKET_ID: "$TICKET_ID" },
         QUERIES: { $push: "$QUERIES" }
      }
   },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$_id"] } } }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a9r3H6GtVfY)

Comment: Thank you @Wernfried Domscheit